# Make Theme Options Menu item more easily / directly accessible

Tags: theme-options

Is there a way to make the Theme Options Menu more visible? It contains my client's many specific options, he will need to access it every once in a while. 
By default, it's pretty well hidden underneath Appearance.

Have you found a good way to bring it upfront?

Answer (score 0):

Theme Options page under Appearance are added by this function.

```
<?php
add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
 ?>
```

To make it appear outside as a top level menu page replace it with following.

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function,$icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

**Where**

$page_title :The text to be displayed in the title tags of the page when the menu is selected.
$menu_title :The text to be used for the menu
$capability :The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user(for add_theme_page generally 'edit_theme_options' and for add_menu_page it is 'manage_options').
$menu_slug : The slug name to refer to this menu(it should be unique.)
$function : The function that displays the page content for the menu page.
$position : The position in the menu order this menu should appear.

*Reference:*

[Add sub menu page to the Appearance menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page)

[Add a top level menu page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)